# Uploading multiple files to firebase and retrieving it's URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

i'm being able to upload the files but i don't know how i can get the URL links. I have the const fileArr which will receive each file, but i don't know how i can access it.

```
  const fileUpload = (name: string) => {
    let fileArr: { name: string; url: string; type: string }[] = [];
    let objectArr: any[] = [];
    Object.entries(file).forEach(([key, value]) => objectArr.push(value));

    if (file !== null) {
      const res = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        objectArr.forEach((item: any) => {
          const fileRef = ref(storage, `${name}/${item.name}`);

          uploadBytes(fileRef, item).then(() => {
            getDownloadURL(fileRef).then((url) => {
              fileArr.push({ name: item.name, url, type: item.type });
            });
          });
          if (!fileArr) {
            reject("error");
          } else {
            resolve(fileArr);
          }
        });
      });
      res
        .then((value) => {
          return value;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    }
  };
```

I'm calling this function like this

```
  const letsTry = () => {
    const result = fileUpload("anyname");
    console.log(result);
  };
```

The console just logs 'undefined'. How should i do this?

**EDIT**
So, at the 'then catch' expression, before it returns i put a console.log. It's logging 'error', but the images are getting uploaded.

```
res
        .then((value) => {
          console.log(value);
          return value;
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          return "error";
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
if (!fileArr) {
```

Since you initialize `fileArray` as `let fileArr: { name: string; url: string; type: string }[] = [];`, it always has a value - even if it is an empty array.

And since both `uploadBytes` and `getDownloadURL` are asynchronous operations, you resolve the promise before any upload has completed.

What you'll want to do is instead check at the end of getting a download URL whether you now have all download URLs that you expect.

You *can* do this with `Promise.all()`, but you can also simply compare the number of the original files you're uploading with the number of download URLs you have, each time you got a new download URL. That should be something like this:

```
objectArr.forEach((item: any) => {
  const fileRef = ref(storage, `${name}/${item.name}`);

  uploadBytes(fileRef, item).then(() => {
    getDownloadURL(fileRef).then((url) => {
      fileArr.push({ name: item.name, url, type: item.type });
      if (fileArr.length === objectArr.length) {
        resolve(fileArr);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your asnwer. But i have two questions. First, if i use Promise.all() i use it like Promise.all(fileArr)? And i'm not sure how can i get the fileArr value. Because my console just logs 'undefined'. I imagine i'm loging it before the promise ends. I'm not sure how i should retrieve the new fileArr value

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying/asking there. Does the code that I show in my answer make sense, and did you try it already? Was there any error message?

Comment: I made a silly mistake before but now it's working! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The 4th line:
Object.entries(file).forEach(([key, value]) => objectArr.push(value));
I think the varible `file` is undefined in line 4.

Comment: I passed it into the if, and gives me the same thing